# Logo image in HTML is not appearing

Tags: html, css

I have a html page which has a logo on the top:

[default logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3YRv.png)

After I resized my logo with the same size and kept it over there, its not appearing:

[current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgIMV.png)

The code for logo is the following

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="relative-logo">
      <img src="assets/images/logo" alt="logo">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="responsive-logo visible-xs">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo-mobile.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
```

The logo is appearing in mobile mode when I did the same with the mobile logo resizing. Can anyone tell me why my logo is not appearing in desktop mode?

Comment: Probably you got the URL wrong. Check the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: What's your website structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the file-extension (`.png`, `.jpg` etc.) in the `src` of the `<img>`. Change

```
<img src="assets/images/logo" alt="logo">
```

to

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

Here is the full code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="relative-logo">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="responsive-logo visible-xs">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo-mobile.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: **Maybe**. URLs without file extensions on them are perfectly valid.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the block.

Comment: @Quentin I disagree. This is not a typo and might even be a common mistake. I fail to see how this can never have any value to anyone.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add a / at the top of src: "/"
This is for absolute path.

Example `<img src="/image.png"/>` --> http://www.something.com/image.png
Example 2 `<img src="/folder/image.png"/>` --> http://www.something.com/folder/image.png

Comment: If the mobile version works this cannot be the solution.